# C# Class Properties Code Difference

Tags: c#, properties

Im quietly confuse on what is the difference between this code

```
class Person
{
    private string name = "N/A";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and this code

```
class Person
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me to explain their use, and when they are being used. The advantage and disadvantage. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

these two pieces of code are exactly the same. When you write the second piece of code the c# compiler actually translates it to the first. It's just a quicker way to write and read it.

However this being said the first example has its uses.

For example if you would like to change the name value in any way before it was set you would have to use the first example.

For example:

```
class Person
{
    private string name = "N/A";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = "My name is:" + value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nit picking: they are not exactly the same: you do not have access to the backing field.

Comment: Ok yea this is true, maybe I should have worded it "the compiled versions" are exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

```
public String Name { get; set; }
```

Above is a short hand way to write a property and are called **automatically implemented properties (AIPs)**. C# compiler will automatically create a private field for these behind the scenes.